# Updating columns in dataframe for rows that exist in reference/lookup dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has some data that has been scaled incorrectly, so I need to apply a correction calculation to 4 columns, *IF* that row/value exists in a reference dataframe

```
df:
devicename|   val1   |   val2   |   val3   |  val4   |    val5    |   val6   |
=============================================================================
dev1         100        200        300       400         500         600
dev2         200        300        400       500         600         700    

sig_ref:
devicename|signalname
=======================
dev1         val1
dev1         val3
dev1         val5
```

so, for each device/value in sig_ref, I need to find all rows in df with that device, and divide df[signalname] by 10. In the example below, the end result will be df dev1.val1=10, val3=30, val5=50, etc.

What I have done:

```
sig_ref = pd.read_csv('./Signals.csv')

df = pd.read_parquet(file)
for index, row in sig_ref.iterrows():
  print('Finding: ', row['devicename'], row['signalname'])
  sig = (row['signalname']).lower()
  print(sig)
  df.loc[df['devicename'] == row['devicename']][sig]/10
```

I have also tried a convoluted 'isin', but could not figure out how to then select the signalnames from the reference dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can try `melt` then `merge`, modify the values, then pivot back:

```
(df.melt('devicename', var_name='signalname')
   .merge(sig_ref, indicator=True, how='left')
   .assign(value = lambda x: np.where(x['_merge']=='both', x['value']/10, x['value'])
          )
   .pivot(index='devicename', columns='signalname', values='value')
)
```

Output:

```
signalname   val1   val2   val3   val4   val5   val6
devicename                                          
dev1         10.0  200.0   30.0  400.0   50.0  600.0
dev2        200.0  300.0  400.0  500.0  600.0  700.0
```